# How to prevent postback if textbox text in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback, onchange

The process is simple:

- Type text into a textbox
- if the text matches a value in the dropdown list update the value.
- If the text does not match a value in the dropdown list do postback using ASP.NET onTextChanged event. *(Here lies the problem. The code below currently prevents postback in all instances)*

**HTML**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="d" runat="Server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="t" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="if(!test(this)) return false;"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function test() {
  var d = ('#<%= d.ClientID%>'),
      t = ('#<%= t.ClientID%>');

  $(d + ',' + t).on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    $(d + ' option').each(function () {
      if (this.value == val) {
        $(d + ',' + t).val(val);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  });
});
```

This code works perfectly for updating the dropdown value. 
The problem is this code prevents postback in all cases.

I think the problem is that onchange is fired from textbox and then the subsequent code inside the javascript onchange will not work.

Comment: what are you trying to say by this _however I cannot get it to return true/false to textbox and prevent/allow postback._

Comment: Try change approach first make AutoPostBack="false" otherwise you will keep on submit to server, then instead make the server hit try using ajax call to get data and populate in dropdown if the text value not already there

Comment: $(d + ',' + t), this was supposed to be a selector. But here its not clear. Change event is on textbox right?

Comment: change event is on both textbox and dropdown. Postback is linked to textbox only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `javascript:return test()` instead of `if(!test(this)) return false;`, like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="t" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" 
 onchange="javascript:return test()"/>
```

and in JavaScript

```
 function test() {
            var d = document.getElementById('d'), t = document.getElementById('t');
            var ddl = ('#d');
            var txt = ('#t');
            var val = t.value;
            var len = $(ddl+ ' option[value=' + val + ']').length;
            if (len > 0) {
                d.value = t.value = val;
                return false;
            } 
                return true;

        }
```

**Update**

Aspx

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="d" runat="Server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onchange="javascript:return test('ddl')"/>

        <asp:TextBox ID="t" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="javascript:return test('txt')" />
```

JavaScript

```
function test(temp) {
            var d = document.getElementById('<%= d.ClientID%>'), t = document.getElementById('<%= t.ClientID%>');
            var ddl = ('#<%= d.ClientID%>');
            var txt = ('#<%= t.ClientID%>');
            var val = t.value;
            if (temp == "txt") {
                var len = $(ddl + ' option[value=' + val + ']').length;

                if (len > 0) {
                    d.value = t.value = val;
                    return false;
                } 
            }
            else {
                t.value = d.value;
                    return false;
                } 
                return true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Sid I already trying this. It does not work in this case.

Comment: are you getting any error or is your `test()` being called?

Comment: No error. Postback does not occur. If I remove the onchange event from textbox entirely, postback occurs everytime as expected. Some how return false is always occuring?

Comment: @Obsidion : try the updated js with `javascript:return test()`

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into this Sid but still no postbacks occur.

Comment: yeah that's true, i also found out that.. however there are more changes which are to be done to make your code work.. working on that too

Comment: @Obsidion no this function won't need each loop, will update the answer soon to call `test()` on change events of textbox and dropdown

Comment: @Obsidion just one query before i update the answer, what do you want to do on `onchange` of dropdown. I mean what should happen after dropdown value is changed?

Comment: 1. On ddl change txt.value = ddl.value. 2. On txt change ddl.selectedvalue = txt.value. 3. If value doesnt exist run servside postback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57681/discussion-between-sid-m-and-obsidion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__doPostBack](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all) instead.

post back when drop down list changed:

```
$(function() {
    var d= $('#<%= d.ClientID%>');
    d.removeAttr('onchange');
    d.change(function(e) {
        //You can decide when to post back
        setTimeout('__doPostBack("<%= d.ClientID%>","")', 0);
    });
});
```

or post back when textbox changed

```
$(function() {
    var t= $('#<%= t.ClientID%>');
    t.removeAttr('onchange');
    t.change(function(e) {
        setTimeout('__doPostBack("<%= t.ClientID%>","")', 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: How then do I prevent postback if the javascript query returns false?

Comment: @Obsidion just not call the __doPostBack function